# Cannot delete broken symbolic link

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, symlink

I have a symbolic link formerly pointing to a Dropbox directory. I don't know what I did wrong, but apparently now it points to itself.

```
hyper@mypi:/home/hyper/test$ ls -l
total 1024
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hyper hyper 7 Feb 15  2013 Dropbox -> Dropbox
```

When I try to remove the link I get:

```
hyper@mypi:/home/hyper/test$ rm Dropbox
rm: cannot remove ‘Dropbox’: Not a directory
```

What else can I try to get rid of this link?

Part of the Output of strace rm Dropbox:

```
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "Dropbox", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=7, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "Dropbox", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=7, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "Dropbox", 0)        = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ce00fc000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7ce00fc000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=619, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 619, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ce00fc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/charset.alias", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "rm: ", 4rm: )                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove \342\200\230Dropbox\342\200\231", 27cannot remove ‘Dropbox’) = 27
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Not a directory", 17: Not a directory)       = 17
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Have you tried `fsck`ing the filesystem? If `/home` is on your root filesystem, you'll have to reboot to do this.

Comment: Do you have an alias for `rm`? What does `strace rm Dropbox` tell you?

Comment: Try `ln -sf`ing to a different location?

Comment: Can you give us the relevant output (at the end) of `strace rm Dropbox`? You could try to create a new folder, move the link there and delete the folder afterwards: `mkdir tmp; mv Dropbox tmp/; rm -rf tmp/`

Comment: I added the output to my first post above.

Comment: is that you can be able to access Dropbox directory through that symbolic link.

Comment: mv: cannot move ‘Dropbox’ to ‘tmp/Dropbox’: Not a directory

Comment: I cannot access the symbolic link: cd: Dropbox: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: Did you create `rm` as alias for `rmdir` command?

Comment: only post the output of `strace rm`.

Comment: It may be that a program is somehow using `Dropbox` as its `pwd` or otherwise. You could try `lsof Dropbox` and close/kill anything that comes up and then try `rm` again.

Answer (score 3):

The error message does not refer to the symlink but to the current directory!

man 2 unlinkat:

> ```
> int unlinkat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags);
> ```
>
> ERRORS
>
> ENOTDIR
>
> pathname is relative and dirfd is a file descriptor referring to a file other than a directory.

Thus you should `cd` at least one level above and have a look at the directory. Has it been deleted or something like that (usually not possible when it is the CWD of a process).

Comment: Good call, this must be the problem. `rm` has no problem deleting a circular symlink: `ln -s foo foo; ls -l foo; rm foo`. OP has probably deleted (or perhaps moved or read-protected) the directory cortaining the symlink. Kill that shell or do a `cd` to your home directory, come back and try again.